# How to fetch connection status from Beeline in Shell Script?

Tags: bash, shell, hadoop, hive, beeline

I am executing a Hive query via beeline from a shellscript.
Below is a sample of the code:
I see that even if connection to Hive Database fails, $? would still return zero as exit code.
**How can I fetch the exit code/connectivity status from beeline for a use case like below ?**
I need to stop the execution of shellscript as soon as beeline fails to connect to DB and a proper message should be logged suggesting Hive Connection failed.

```
beeline -u $HIVE_CONNECTION_STRING  --outputformat=csv2 -f $LOCATION_OF_HIVE_SELECT_QUERY_FILE > QueryResults.csv

if [$? -ne 0]; then 
   echo "Could not connect to DB."
   exit 1
else
   #Do rest of the process since data was fetched from DB successfully above
fi
```

Comment: hi, have you solved this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a whitespace `- ne` where you shouldn't.  Try this `-ne`:

```
beeline -u $HIVE_CONNECTION_STRING  --outputformat=csv2 -f $LOCATION_OF_HIVE_SELECT_QUERY_FILE > QueryResults.csv

if [$? -ne 0]; then 
   echo "Could not connect to DB."
   exit 1
else
   #Do rest of the process since data was fetched from DB successfully above
fi
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. I checked my actual shell script that I am executing and there was no whitespace in '- ne'. It was a typo here, I just fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use `$?`. Just put the command into the `if` condition and exchange `then` and `else` clause.

```sh
if beeline -u "$HIVE_CONNECTION_STRING" --outputformat=csv2 -f "$LOCATION_OF_HIVE_SELECT_QUERY_FILE" > QueryResults.csv
then 
  #Do rest of the process since data was fetched from DB successfully above
else
  echo "Could not connect to DB."
  exit 1
fi
```

Btw: **Always** double-quote variables in program arguments.